# How to track Facebook Save Button clicks in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-tag-manager

I would like to track Facebook Save Button click events with Google Tag Manager. The button is embedded via JavaScript SDK on a website.

Comment: Please add more details, screenshots, snippets, tag configurations, etc., and show the code you've tried. No code gets your post closed.

Comment: Here you find details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/save
is it not engough to add Referrer in ` data-uri="domain.tld/product-abc/?myReferrerID=Facebook_Save_Button"` (you have to replace myReferrer with a Google Track Event)